# How to inject factory in angular boostrap modal's controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to create dialog box for confirmation on Submit button. So I am using angular ui bootstrap.

This is my main controller code:

```
FrontEnd.controller('PostViewController',function($scope,$stateParams,PostFactory, $modal){

    $scope.openConfirm = function(size) {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'ConfirmDialog.html',
                controller: 'ConfirmDialogController',
                size: size, 
                resolve: {
                    form: function () {
                            return $scope.form;
                        },
                    //tried with this line as well, but could not resolve error
                    PostFactory: "PostFactory"   
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (response) {
                $scope.isSurveySubmitted = true;
                $scope.message = response.message;

                //$scope.selected = selectedItem;
              }, function () {
                console.log('Modal dismissed at: ');
            });
    };
});
```

This is my ConfirmDialogController:

```
FrontEnd.controller('ConfirmDialogController', function($scope, $http, $modalInstance, form, PostFactory){

    $scope.ok = function () {

        PostFactory.SubmitSurvey(form).success(function(response){
            $modalInstance.close(response);
        }).success(function(response){
            $modalInstance.close(response);
        });
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Modal opens properly without error. When I click on cancel button it closes modal As I expected. But when I click on **Ok**, it calls **$scope.ok()** but throws error in console with message PostFactory is undefined.

So what to do? Thanks for help.

Comment: so where is the code for PostFactory??? Error is very clear and to the point

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `scope` field in `$modalInstance.open()`

set the factory as a property on a new scope

```
var scope = $scope.$new();
scope.factory = PostFactory;
$modalInstance.open({
    // other stuff
    scope: scope
});
```

Then reference the $scope.factory in yoou modal's controller.

not sure if it will mess anything else up, worth a try though.

Comment: +1 on this. You can tell $modal which scope to use so you can just use the same $scope as in your parent controller

Comment: or set the factory on the PostViewController $scope, and pass `{ scope: $scope }` to the modalInstance. [What @Dan said]

Comment: Sorry. My code worked. It was not working bcoz I was trying with **PostFactory: "PostFactory"** in resolve statement. So just removed that statement, and it worked. Btw thank you very much both of you for giving me more info on how to pass scope to modal. Cheers!